# "So I am a younger brother to 3 siblings..." Does this mean there are 4 siblings or 3 siblings in total?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language

**"I am a younger brother to 3 siblings."**

I thought the sentence means "I am the youngest of 3 siblings." But then I got confused because maybe the sentence means "There are 4 siblings and he is the youngest one and the remaining 3 siblings are all older than him.

So, I needed to ask. Is this structure idiomatic? And if yes, are there 4 siblings or 3 siblings in total?

Comment: It means that he is the youngest of four. He is 'younger brother' to all three of the others.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks, that was informative. Considering "I am younger brother to 3 siblings", does this also mean the 3 others are also male siblings or they might be male or female?

Comment: _Siblings_, by definition, includes brothers _and_ sisters.